# How to make the options menu doesn't disappear when video is paused

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I was building my own custom Video player and I'm tried to make the options bar/menu disappear when the user is inactive It works and everything, But I still want it to stay shown only when the video is paused,
How can I do that?

> My Code
> Blockquote

```
const refs = useRef(null)
    let timeStep = 10
    let volumeBar;
    
    // Play
    const [isPlay, setPlay] = useState(false)
    const handlePlay = () => {
        if(isPlay){
            refs.current?.firstChild?.children[0].pause()
            setPlay(false)
        }else{
            refs.current?.firstChild?.children[0].play()
            setPlay(true)
        }
    }
```

```
// Video Hover
    const handleVideoHover = (e) => {
        console.log(e.type)
        const videoOptions = document.querySelector('.video-options-container')
        let timeOut
        clearTimeout(timeOut)
        if(!isPlay || e.type === 'mousemove' || e.type === 'touchstart' || e.type === 'click'|| e.type === 'keydown'){
            videoOptions.style = ` opacity: 1; transition: opacity 0.5s;`
        }
        timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
            videoOptions.style = ` opacity: 0; transition: opacity 2.5s;`
        }, 2000)
    }
```

```
// JSX
<div className='video-container w-100 h-100' onClick={handleVideoHover} onKeyDown={handleVideoHover} onMouseMove={handleVideoHover} onTouchStart={handleVideoHover} onMouseLeave={handleVideoHover}>
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this useful

I made this. I know, is verbose but is a solution

```
const refs = useRef(null)
let timeStep = 10
let volumeBar;

// Play
const [isPlay, setPlay] = useState(false)
let timeOut;

const handlePlay = () => {
const videoOptions = document.querySelector('.video-options-container')
    if(isPlay){
        videoOptions.style = `opacity: 1; transition: opacity 0.5s;`;
        clearTimeout(timeOut);
        refs.current?.firstChild?.children[0].pause()
        setPlay(false)
    }else{
        refs.current?.firstChild?.children[0].play();
        timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
            videoOptions.style = ` opacity: 0; transition: opacity 2.5s;`
        }, 2000)
        setPlay(true)
    }
}
```

and:

```
const handleVideoHover = (e) => {
    console.log(e.type)
    const videoOptions = document.querySelector('.video-options-container')
    clearTimeout(timeOut)
    if(!isPlay || e.type === 'mousemove' || e.type === 'touchstart' || e.type === 'click'|| e.type === 'keydown'){
        videoOptions.style = ` opacity: 1; transition: opacity 0.5s;`
    }
    if(!isPlay)return;
    timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
        videoOptions.style = ` opacity: 0; transition: opacity 2.5s;`
    }, 2000)
}
```

I removed timeOut from hendleVideoHover function and I put in a JSX main funtion:

```
const refs = useRef(null)
let timeStep = 10
let volumeBar;

// Play
const [isPlay, setPlay] = useState(false)

let timeOut;
```

works to me. I hope to be usefull